# How to convert a number to a string collection

Tags: java

e.g.:

- If the number is 234, I would like the result to be `List<String>` containing `2,3,4` (3 elements)
- If the number is 8763, I would like the result to be `List<String>` containing `8,7,6,3` (4 elements)

Does commons-math already have such a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Convert the number to a String (`123` becomes `"123"`). Use `Integer.toString`.
2. Convert the string to a char array (`"123"` becomes `{'1', '2', '3'}`). Use `String.toCharArray`.
3. Construct a new, empty `Vector<String>` (or some other List type).
4. Convert each char in the char array to a String and push it onto the Vector (`{'1', '2', '3'}` becomes a Vector with `"1"`, `"2"` and `"3"`). Use a for loop, `Character.toString` and `List.add`.

**Edit**: You can't use the Vector constructor; have to do it manually.

```
int num = 123;
char[] chars = Integer.toString(num).toCharArray();
List<String> parts = new Vector<String>();
for (char c : chars)
{
    parts.add(Character.toString(c));
}
```

There isn't an easier way to do this because it really isn't a very obvious or common thing to want to do. For one thing, why do you need a List of *Strings*? Can you just have a list of *Characters*? That would eliminate step 3. Secondly, does it have to be a *List* or can it just be an array? That would eliminate step 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in java.util.Arrays.asList:

```
int num = 234;
List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(num).split("\\B"));
```

Step by step this:

1. Converts `num` to a `String` using `String.valueOf(num)`
2. Splits the String by non-word boundaries, in this case, every letter boundary except the start and the finish, using `.split("\\B")` (this returns a `String[]`)
3. Converts the `String[]` to a `List<String>` using `Arrays.asList(T...)`

Comment: It will include 4 elements: `{"", "2", "3", "4"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.asList( String.valueOf(number).toCharArray() )
```

Comment: Won't this return a List<Character> instead of a List<String>?

Comment: Arrays.asList( char[] ) will return a List<char[]> .. so dont think this will work.

Comment: Yeah I tried this. `Arrays.asList` is a really crazy function. [The documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) doesn't really explain it, but it seems like if and only if you give it an array of objects (not an array of primitives), it will turn that array into a List. Otherwise, it will take any number of arguments and put them all into a list. So this works for a String[], not for a char[].

Comment: @mgiuca: it has to do with varargs -- signatures of `foo(T[])` and `foo(T...)` are really the same, besides that, parameterized types `T` must be non primitive, so the compiler assumes you meant a type of primitive array `t[]` for `T`.

Comment: Ah, cheers. I have spent the past 20 minutes trying to figure out how the hell that worked (in terms of the types). That makes sense. I don't think T[] and T... are the same, since T... allows you to pass an array or many arguments, whereas T[] only allows you to pass an array. So it's more like there is an "auto-splat" happening if you try to pass an array where var-args are expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(1234).split("(?!^)"))
```

It will create list of Strings:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like homework.

Consider using `%` and `/` to get each digit instead of converting the entire number to a String